Compliance with Open-Source Licenses in Proprietary Software Using Hibernate 5.6.15 licensed under LGPL v2.1
I want to distributing proprietary software under a strict End User License Agreement (EULA) that:

Prohibits derivative works
Distributes the software and libraries in object code form only

My software uses Hibernate 5.6.15, which is licensed under the LGPL v2.1.  Hibernate also has dependencies with different open-source licenses, including:

BSD
Apache 2.0
EDL 1.0
EDL 1.0 + EPL 2.0
EPL 2.0 + GPL 2
CDDL 1.1 + GPL2 w/ CPE

Am I obliged to include the licenses of all these dependencies in my distribution?

When distributing the software you have to comply with all the requirements (providing attribution, notices, license language, ...) listed in each of the mentioned licenses. If your software is using libraries with all of the licenses you mentioned, then you will not be able to distribute it under an EULA. You will likely have to distribute it under GPL. You might want to reconsider your project plan!

To stress Martin's remark: you do not only have to distribute each license text, you also have to comply with each. Thus the license texts alone might not be enough. There is nothing to balance, though - you must not use the libraries, if you don't intend to (or cannot) comply.

The question significantly changed after my first comment, the list of licenses to comply with is much shorter. I am interpreting the ‘+’ in the license list as an indicator for dual licensing. I am assuming that you use Hibernate 5.6.15 and its dependencies without any modifications.
You will have to comply with the terms of each of the listed licenses including the licenses of all direct and indirect dependencies. That means that you have to provide information about the libraries, their author(s), their licenses, sometimes also the complete license language. You should read each of the licenses and comply. An example of how the information/publication part can be done is the list of 3rd party libraries in Adobe products. You can also put the information in an ‘About’-page in the UI of your software or somewhere else where it can easily be found.
The most restrictive license in your list is LGPL v2.1, all the other licenses (if you opt for the least restrictive option in case of the dual-licensed libraries) are permissive. Sections 5 and 6 of LGPL v2.1 allow you to use a library under LGPL 2.1 in a proprietary program (which you may distribute under any terms of your choice, including EULA). You need to read Sections 5 and 6 of LGPL 2.1 carefully and comply with each of the requirements.
Compliance with LGPL 2.1 does not take away your requirement to comply with all of the license terms of the dependencies.
